# Segmented far pointer allocation in 16bit x86 MS-DOS real mode

Tags: c, dos, x86-16, real-mode, watcom

I'm trying to get my head around programming real mode MS-DOS in C. Using some old books on game programming as a starting point.
The source code in the book is written for Microsoft C, but I'm trying to get it to compile under OpenWatcom v2. I've run into a problem early on, when trying to access a pointer to the start of VGA video memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>

void Set_Video_Mode(int mode) {
    
    union REGS inregs, outregs;

    inregs.h.ah = 0; 
    inregs.h.al = (unsigned char) mode;

    int86(0x10, &inregs, &outregs);
}


int main(void)
{
    Set_Video_Mode(0x13);

    //the following line throws an error, without it the code compiles and runs
    char far *video_buffer = (char far *)0xA0000000L;

    while (!kbhit()) { };

    Set_Video_Mode(0x03);

    return 0;
}
```

It's the far pointer assignment that throws the following errors:

> VGA.C(33): Error! E1077: Missing '}' 
> VGA.C(33): Warning! W107: Missing return value for function 'main' 
> VGA.C(36): Error! E1099: Statement must be inside function. Probable cause: missing {

Which is kind of baffling, and seems like a macro definition gone wrong, or something...

When I try the code from the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer) on far pointers, with the same compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char far *p = (char far *)0x55550005;
    char far *q = (char far *)0x53332225;
    *p = 80;
    (*p)++;
    printf("%d", *q);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles.
The compile command is `wcl -bcl=dos source.c` in both cases.

So I'm kind of stumped now, and can't seem to pinpoint the problem.
I'm on the verge of throwing a few asterisks and brackets at random places to see if it sticks somewhere...

Comment: I see two differences between the sample you say does compile and one that does not: A) You included `dos.h` in the problem example, maybe there is something in that file that break compilation? B) Your use of `L` at the end of the pointer value. Maybe this particular compiler does not know it?

Comment: Note that the semicolon at the end of your `while` line is superfluous.

Comment: Can't you cross-compile with GCC?

Comment: @einpoklum GCC doesn't have proper support for 16-bit segmented code or DOS. There is  a ia16-gcc port of GCC but it is still unstable. That being said the ia16-gcc port is an interesting project but not ready for prime time.

Comment: It's not dos.h. it's the standard DOS header needed for bios functions for video mode access in this case. I tried with it included in the second example without any effect. Likewise for the 'L' long literal.
@Adrian Mole - good catch. See, I already started throwing random brackets around. Sigh.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Ok... what about Borland C then? I remember that used to run on DOS.

Comment: @einpoklum - the thing about OpenWatcom is its ability to cross-compile from modern OS-es. Although I'm not doing it in this case. Compiling with DOS version in dosbox-x. In any case Watcom is quite a standard later-era DOS compiler, probably one of the best and most famous. It's not it that's wrong, it's me, I just don't know how or where...

Comment: Try replacing the assignment with `char far *video_buffer = NULL;` to check which part of the assignment causes a problem.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - I just abbreviated that for clarity in the post. In actual code the function is implemented before main().

Comment: I don't remember well as a `far` pointer was encoded in the compiler form, but the x86 segmented processors were limited to 20bits of addressing, with the segment register value shifted by 4 and added to the 16 bits address to form the 20 bits physical address. Maybe the address `0xA0000000` is too large and has the MSB set. The VGA text memory starts at `0xB8000` as far as I know, which is in the 20 bits addressing range. All the address used in the examples you posted are outside of the addressing range for a 16bits segmented processor.

Comment: @Frankie_C : `far` pointers do exist in Watcom and they are encoded as 32 bit value with the segment in the upper 16 bit and the offset in the lower 16-bits. There is also a macro `MK_FP` that can make a far pointer out of a segment and offset value.  0xA0000000 would be interpreted by the Watcom DOS compiler as 0xa000:0x0000 which is the EGA/VGA graphics area (64KiB). Mode 0x13 (the OP is apparently doing that) would be using that area as video ram.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes I remember now, `MK_FP`, defined in `dos.h`, so the physical address for the far pointer `0xA0000000` is `0xA0000` graphic memory of VGA.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - it indeed does compile when I comment out those lines! As it does compile when I comment out the far pointer line... but together it breaks. I edited the original post to include the Set_Vide_Mode function.

Comment: And this is why reducing to a [mcve] is useful for debugging.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears your OpenWatcom C compiler is defaulting to using C89. In C89 variable declarations must be at the beginning of a block scope. In your case all your code and data is at function scope, so the variable has to be declared at the beginning of `main` before the code.

Moving the variable declaration this way should be C89 compatible:

```
int main(void)
{
    char far *video_buffer = (char far *)0xA0000000L;

    Set_Video_Mode(0x13);
    while (!kbhit()) { };
    Set_Video_Mode(0x03);

    return 0;
}
```

If using OpenWatcom 2.0 as you suggest you are, you should be able to compile with C99 mode by adding the option `-za99` to the `wcl` options. In C99 you can  place variable declarations in places other than top of block scope.

---

When compiling as C89, Watcom extended C89 to allow C++ style comments the same way C99 supports it. This behaviour seem to be [documented](https://open-watcom.github.io/open-watcom-v2-wikidocs/clr.html#Comments) as:

> The Open Watcom C/16 and C/32 compilers support an extension for comments.  The symbol // can be used at any point in a physical source line (except inside a character constant or string literal).  Any characters from the // to the end of the line are treated as comment characters.  The comment is terminated by the end of the line.

I agree with the assessment that had the C++ style comments not been allowed, the compiler would have given a much better picture of what the real problem was. I too was fooled at first and it didn't occur to me right away that it was being compiled as C89 code. I had assumed since the `//` was accepted that it must have been C99.

Comment: nitpick: C89 allows declarations at the top of any scope, not just whole-function scope.  e.g. `{ int foo; ... }`.  https://godbolt.org/z/TzrKhc4WY shows GCC and clang allow that with `-std=c89 -Wall -pedantic`, but warn without the extra `{}` for a new scope, which I think is accurate to ISO C89.

Comment: Yes, that's it! It's kind of weird that it still does accept line comments in c89 mode - that would be a dead giveaway if it didn't. I guess stuff like that was added as soon as it was available back then, before formal standardization.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Thanks I fixed it. My original wording was directed to the sample and it should have been a general statement.

Comment: @IronPug : In fact the C++ style comments in your code deceived me as well. Since it never complained about them I had assumed it defaulted to C99 so it caused me head scratching.  I forgot that Watcom added an extension for comments to allow `//` in C89.